# how to fix :TypeError: can't pickle Selector objects

Tags: python, pickle, scrapy

Hello， I want to change my crawlspider to rediscrawlspider，and then the bug appear：

```
2019-01-09 10:28:54 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-01-09 10:28:54 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 517, in _oneWorkUnit
result = next(self._iterator)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 63, in 
work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 183, in _process_spidermw_output
self.crawler.engine.crawl(request=output, spider=spider)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 210, in crawl
self.schedule(request, spider)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 216, in schedule
if not self.slot.scheduler.enqueue_request(request):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_redis\scheduler.py", line 167, in enqueue_request
self.queue.push(request)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_redis\queue.py", line 99, in push
data = self._encode_request(request)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_redis\queue.py", line 43, in _encode_request
return self.serializer.dumps(obj)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_redis\picklecompat.py", line 14, in dumps
return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=-1)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 204, in getstate
raise TypeError("can't pickle Selector objects")
TypeError: can't pickle Selector objects
```

the pip list:

```
lxml 4.1.0
parsel 1.5.0
pywin32 221
redis 2.10.6
requests 2.18.4
Scrapy 1.5.1
scrapy-redis 0.6.8
scrapyd 1.2.0
testpath 0.3.1
Twisted 17.9.0
urllib3 1.22
python 3.6.7
```

I know the bug mean but I just want to use `rediscrawlspider` to dupefilter, why the selector appear?
Additional, if I del the callback of rule, it work fine but make no sence:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@Class="pj-box-li"]', allow=r'/project/.+'), callback='parse_detail')
```

I try to check the pywin module but it works good

I want the spider run fine; 
Additional why the bug appear? I just want to pick urls.

Answer (score 0):

I find the bug！I use the loader in meta，but and when pickle the request will pick the loader too，so the bug appear！